# Not able to submit the data to firebase from contact form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
        import styled from 'styled-components'
        import Title from '../Components/Title'
        import { InnerLayout, MainLayout } from '../Styles/Layout'
        import Button from '../Components/Button'
        import { db } from '../firebase';
        
        function Contact() {
            const [name, setName] = useState("");
            const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
            const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
            const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
        
            const handleSubmit = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
        
                db.collection('mail').add({
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    subject: subject,
                    message: message,
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        alert("Thank you for contacting. Your message has been sent successfully.");
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        alert(err.message);
                    });
        
                setName('')
                setEmail('')
                setSubject('')
                setMessage('')
            };
        
            return (
                <MainLayout>
                    <Title title={'Contact'} span={'Contact'} />
                    <ContactMain>
                        <InnerLayout className='contact-section'>
                            <div className="left-content">
                                <div className="contact-title">
                                    <h4>Get In Touch</h4>
                                </div>
                                <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="form-field">
                                        <label htmlFor="name">Enter Your Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-field">
                                        <label htmlFor="email">Enter Your Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-field">
                                        <label htmlFor="subject">Enter Your Subject</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" value={subject} onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-field">
                                        <label htmlFor="text-area">Enter Your Message</label>
                                        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-field f-button">
                                        <Button title="Send Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </InnerLayout>
                    </ContactMain>
                </MainLayout>
        
            )
    }
```

I don't know why but I am not able to send the details to my firebase database. I am not able to find the issue in this code. I have copied the firebase database key and all in the firebase.js and then imported it in this contact.js and I then made the necessary changes in this. Still, I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Does the console have an error message?

Comment: No, I am not getting an error but got a warning, I have added that above.

Comment: If you `import firebase from "firebase/app"` instead of `.. from "firebase"` the warning should be go.

Comment: Thank you. That warning is gone but it is still not working

Comment: Hello, any updates on this? If my answer was useful you can accept (✔) and upvote () it. Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Warning is gone but the main issue is not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

I would reset the form once the promise returned by `add()` is resolved.

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  db.collection('mail').add({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    subject: subject,
    message: message,
  }).then(() => {
    // Reset those states here
    setName('')
    setEmail('')
    setSubject('')
    setMessage('')
    alert("Thank you for contacting. Your message has been sent successfully.");
  }).catch((err) => {
    alert(err.message);
  });
};
```

I guess your states are being reset to `""` before the document is added as those `setState` methods would have ran before the doc was added.

Comment: still, nothing is happening, neither I am getting the data nor the places are getting cleared

Comment: @FaizanLambe can you please add `console.log("Adding data", name, email)` in `handleSubmit` function so we know it is being clicked??

Comment: No, I didn't get the output there.

Comment: @FaizanLambe if the logs are not showing anything then that means your function is not being triggered. Can you try running the function in submit button click instead of form's onSubmit ?

Comment: No, still not getting it

Answer (score 0):

Potentially because your button html within its the button component type is not set to 'submit' - I had the same issue I think which ended up being super simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).